# Android studio Navigation drawer - Expression expected

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to create a tutorial app. I'm getting a message saying

> expression expected

under

```
case 2:
    Activity = new Lesson111();
    break;
```

**Note** - This is not the whole code of my main activity. However, the problem starts when I change

```
case 2:
    fragment = new Lesson111();
    break;
```

to

```
case 2:
    Activity = new Lesson111();
    break;
```

Here is my **Main.Activity**:

```
public class NavigationActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ImageView home;
    Fragment fragment = null;
    TextView appname;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    List<String> listDataHeader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
        home = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.home);
        home.setOnClickListener(homeOnclickListener);
        appname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.appname);
        setUpDrawer();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Get the names and icons references to build the drawer menu...
     */
    private void setUpDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerListener);
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        prepareListData();
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        fragment = new Lesson1();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);

        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                switch (groupPosition) {
                case 0:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new Lesson1();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new Lesson11();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Activity = new Lesson111();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
```

Comment: You havent initialized an Activity variable. Try something like Activity activity = new Lesson111();

Comment: i tried what you said. However it is saying Incompatible types. Also the "activity" is grayed out. And it also says- Required: android.app.Activity Found: com.android.pet.view.Lesson111

Comment: Cause you didn't actually instantiated an Activity instance. Right now it's just hanging there. What are you trying to accomplish? Update your question with more info please

Comment: Im trying to accomplish a radio button inside a collapsible navigation drawer. I already have the fragment that handles the radio buttons. the thing is im trying to call it to my main activity so that when i click the Lesson 111 in my collapsible menu on my left screen, I will see the radio buttons on my right screen.

Comment: @OnurÇevik sorry, I was unable to update my java file, it was still on Lesson111 extends fragment. I forgot to change it to Lesson111 extends Activity. Im going to try to run it now.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by this response. Thank you

You havent initialized an Activity variable. Try something like Activity activity = new Lesson111(); – Onur Çevik

Comment: [Update] As I've tried the code that Onur Cevik said, Im not having anymore errors. However, the fragment is not showing in my navigation drawer. It looks like the case 2:
    Activity = new Lesson111();
    break; is not working. There are no errors on the code that its showing. The case statement is just not working for the Lesson111.